# printing system command to text file c++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have the following code, but when I run it, the output is printed instead of being copied to the text file.

```
void checkText()
{
    ifstream my_file("test.txt");
    if (my_file.good()) {
        cout << "File exist" ;
    }
    else {
        ofstream outputFile;
        outputFile.open("test.txt");
        outputFile << system("head -n 1024 words.txt");
        outputFile.close();
        cout << "Done!\n";
    }
}
```

How do I print the system command to my text file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix)

Answer (score 1):

[system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) returns an `int` and not the "output" from the command that is executed.

One way to do this would be to redirect the command to the file you want:

```
    std::system("head -n 1024 words.txt > test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 
for printing the output in a text file
freopen(); command

```
freopen("input file name.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("output file name.txt", "w", stdout);
```